# Properties Service object not string in google web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having the app run as the user (so it can manipulate their files) but I'm writing the input and successfully using it in one function, but later when I retrieve it is an object rather than a string.

In function 1 (it definitely is a working gdrive id string here)

```
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('spreadsheetId', gDrive);
```

In function 2:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var gDrive = userProperties.getProperty('spreadsheetId').toString();
```

creates output:

> Spreadsheet Name: [Ljava.lang.Object;@5b133253

Adding the .toString method did nothing to fix it.

Comment: In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide a sample script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making sure it was a string when it went into the userproperties:

```
 userProperties.setProperty('spreadsheetId', gDrive.toString());
```